# Liferay/jboss : no response after hot deploying a war

Tags: jboss, liferay-6

When I start jboss server with liferay (6.2), everything works. I can access the portal, access the administration section of liferay, even war deployed outside of liferay (activiti-explorer,...)

But when I hot deploy a war with portlets, jboss is still running but I can't access anything, even war deployed outside of liferay.

In chrome, i get a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for any url pointing to the jboss server.

In the jboss console, there is nothing showing up after liferay telling the war has been deployed.

Could you help or indicate me leads to resolve my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You know that in the default configuration of JBoss you will see the messages of your deployments only in the configured logging of these deployments? For example Liferay messages will only log to `liferay/logs`. You should use `-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false` as commandline parameter, if you like to see all log messages in the JBoss log.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but adding the parameter did not make some extra trace in the logs...